# java.net.SocketException in URI in Broken Pipe: Can this lead to High CPU usages

Tags: java, sockets, out-of-memory, cpu-usage, socketexception

I am getting an exception:

```
java.net.SocketException in URI: /com/ui/table/CMnTableCompJsp.jsp
Broken pipe
```

There are more than 500+ instances of this error.
This happens because server is trying to write to an already closed connection.

Can 500+ instances of this lead to High CPU utilization or OOM issue?

Comment: Is each message fir the same socket?

Comment: Nope. They are all for different sockets, different users.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you ignore it and don't close the socket and keep trying to write to it.

As this appears to be a JSP page the exception will be arising because a browser closed the connection. This can happen any time under the user's control. Arguably you shouldn't be logging it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to stepback and ask yourself why that message is being output. Somewhere in your program the exception is being caught and printed out. *Where* and *why*.

1. You should catch an exception only if you can handle it (at least in part), or to report it as an indication of a bug. Is the code that caught and printed that exception handling the broken pipe?  If not, fixing that bug should be your real task. If it is handling the broken pipie, you know that the program is behaving well and you have nothing to worry about. When you first attempt to write to a socket that has been closed at the other end, the JRE should throw an exception.  Is the code that catches *that* exception handling disconnection correctly?
2. You should output the stacktrace of an exception only if that exception indicates a bug (stacktraces are programmer speak). You do not seem to consider it to indicate a bug, so fix your logging code. I suspect you have a vast spew of other exception nessages and the reason you are asking here is because you do not know which ones are the "important" ones.
3. You should output a message reporting an event only if that message is useful to someone. That you are asking a question here about whether a message output *by your own program* indicates something important shows that the message, in its current form, is not useful. Perhaps if it had said something more informative ("user disconnected", for example), you would  have saved some time.